# Touchpad and internal keyboard problem Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: boot, keyboard, touchpad

Hi There/Hello AskUbuntu Community, I have a question regarding the internal touchpad and keyboard not working in Ubuntu- basically sometimes when I boot my Computer my internal touchpad and keyboard does not work however my external mouse and keyboard works fine, Internal keyboard and touchpad works every time with Microsoft Windows but whenever I boot a Linux operating system it happens. I hope there's a solution to this problem. I value any support,comments and help.

For information (PC) :

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`lsusb` :

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3b1 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 007: ID 0930:0220 Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lspci` :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 14h Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wrestler [Radeon HD 7310]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wrestler HDMI Audio
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 14)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:15.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
00:15.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0 (rev 43)
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7
06:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
```

Comment: Also By the way I just wanted to say my model is a Toshiba Laptop (SATELLITE C50D- A-11Q). Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed. The computer originally came with Microsoft Windows 8 pre-release.

Comment: Could you edit your post with a copy/paste of the output of the following commands: ```xinput list```, ```lsusb```, ```lspci``` ?

Comment: Okay I guess, why is that a fix? lol.

Comment: I added it to my post , Umm I don't really know how to do it like others because I am actually new to this site and StackExchange.

Comment: By "the output of the following commands" I meant, you have to open a terminal and run these commands one by one and copy/paste the output. To open a terminal press Ctrl+alt+t or alternatively press the super key (the key with the windows symbol) and write "terminal" in the search bar and then press enter to open it. You can then write ```xinput list```, press enter and copy paste the output. Do it for the three commands. These commands display information about your hardware, which should help the community to know a bit more about your problem.

Comment: Sorry my bad I didn't know. I will do this immediately though Thank You.

Comment: Is it 20.04, or 22.04?

Comment: are you sure it's 20.04 ? It shows you use wayland which is not default in 20.04. Also you wrote "basically sometimes when I boot my Computer my internal touchpad and keyboard does not work". Is it always the case or is it really "sometimes"? Is it for example only not working when you have both keyboards (external and internal) connected?

Comment: Try installing libinput-tools with the command ```sudo apt install libinput-tools``` and then run ```libinput list-devices | grep "Device"```. You can then copy/paste the output of the last command in your post, instead of the ```xinput list``` command. xinput is for xorg, libinput for wayland

Comment: I am using JammyJellyfish Ubuntu 22.04 LongTermSupport Version I recently upgraded.